# AWS CLI: Describing a Policy Without "p-" Prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-iam, aws-organizations

I am trying to use AWS CLI to describe my AWS policy. However, AWS does not seem to be recognizing the policy-id.

I have executed this:

`aws iam get-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::160936793253:policy/MyAWSPolicy`

and got the following returned:

```
{
    "Policy": {
        "PolicyName": "MyAWSPolicy",
        "PolicyId": "ANPAIIJNOIYOWCAK6KH7I",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::160936796653:policy/MyAWSPolicy",
        "Path": "/",
        "DefaultVersionId": "v8",
        "AttachmentCount": 2,
        "IsAttachable": true,
        "CreateDate": "2019-03-20T20:20:26Z",
        "UpdateDate": "2019-04-01T18:19:08Z"
    }
}
```

However when I enter in this command:
`aws organizations describe-policy --policy-id ANPAIIJNOIYOWCAK6KH7I`

I get an InvalidInputException because according to AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/describe-policy.html#examples):

> The unique identifier (ID) of the policy that you want details about. You can get the ID from the ListPolicies or ListPoliciesForTarget operations.
>
> The regex pattern for a policy ID string requires "p-" followed by from 8 to 128 lower-case letters or digits.

However when I add `p`- to `ANPAIIJNOIYOWCAK6KH7I` AWS does not recognize this policy.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Nicholas is right, you are using the wrong command. To get the policy details, you need to run the following command: `aws iam get-policy-version --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::160936793253:policy/MyAWSPolicy --version-id v8`. Details can be found: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy-version.html. In this scenario, you need to run 2 commands to get what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you reference suggests that you get the policy id from [ListPolicies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-policies.html) or [ListPoliciesForTarget](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/list-policies-for-target.html) operations, which is likely referencing the operations on the [organizations service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/organizations/index.html#available-commands).  The ID you took is from an IAM policy.

I am not completely familiar with the interactions between IAM and orgnaizations, but I imagine they are using different policy objects with different identifiers.